# WCF REST service doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I created simple WCF web service project and enable the soap and rest service on it.

The soap service works fine but I can't use the rest service and help page.

Here is how I did it:

1. my web service class:

   ```
   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "/InsertWithDate/personTypeName({personTypeName})/accessName({accessName})/firstName({firstName})/lastName({lastName})/nationalID({nationalID})/email({email})/userName({userName})/passwordHash({passwordHash})/genderName({genderName})/statusName({statusName})")]
   [Description("Description for GET /InsertWithDate")]
   string InsertWithDate(string personTypeName, string accessName, string firstName, string lastName, string nationalID, string email, string userName, string passwordHash, string genderName, string statusName);
   ```
2. my `web.config` file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
      <appSettings>
         <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" 
              value="true" />
          <!-- (Log4net diagnostics) -->
          <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
         <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
         <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
          <!-- Add Rest service -->
          <services>
              <service name="WcfWebService.TestWS" 
                       behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
              <!-- Use a bindingNamespace to eliminate tempuri.org. 
              bindingNamespace="http://contoso.com/services" -->
                 <endpoint 
                     address="soap" 
                     binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                     contract="WcfWebService.ITestWS"/>
                 <endpoint 
                     address="rest" 
                     binding="webHttpBinding" 
                     behaviorConfiguration="http" 
                     contract="WcfWebService.ITestWS"/>
                 <endpoint 
                     address="mex" 
                     binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                     contract="IMetadataExchange" />
              </service>
          </services>
          <behaviors>
             <serviceBehaviors>
             <!-- Web service behavior (All kind of web Services hast it) -->
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                </behavior>               
             </serviceBehaviors>
             <!-- Rest service behavier) -->
             <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="http">
                   <webHttp/>
                </behavior>
             </endpointBehaviors>
         </behaviors>
         <protocolMapping>
             <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
         </protocolMapping>    
         <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
         <standardEndpoints>
             <webHttpEndpoint>
                 <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"  
                          automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
             </webHttpEndpoint>
         </standardEndpoints>
     </system.serviceModel>
     <system.webServer>
         <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
         <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```

Now when I try these pages:

1. *localhost:51850/TestWS.svc/help*
2. *localhost:51850/TestWS.svc/InsertWithDate/help*
3. *localhost:51850/TestWS.svc/InsertWithDate/personTypeName(10)/accessName(10)/firstName(mn)/lastName(mn)/nationalID(12)/email(a@asd.com)/userName(nvcvncm)/passwordHash(123)/genderName(male)/statusName(d)*

The same page appears: Server Error in '/' Application.

thank you.

Update:
there is no error: just this page:
[image]

Comment: PLease post full error details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad: I completely forgot about my REST service Address which it was: rest
and also for enabling the help page I just add `<webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>` to my `web.conf` file.